# Binary encoding of non-2^N-integers

Tags: encoding, integer, genetic-algorithm

which is the best way/proper way to deal with integers that cannot be coded as full power of two's and the solution range cannot be simply extended? For example, I might have a limit of 6 instead of 8 because only 6 possible outcomes exist:
    000 -> possible outcome, low fitness
    001 -> -"-, higher fitness
    ..
    011 -> possible, high fitness
    100 -> possible, highest fitness
    101 -> infeasible, zero fitness (?)
    111 -> infeasible, zero fitness (?)

Thanks&kind regards

Comment: In which context do you need to encode these numbers? Why can’t you just encode the “underlying integer value”?

Comment: The integers represent percentages of a raw material in a product. 000 .. 50 %, 001 .. 60 %, .. , 101 .. 100 % (and 110 would be 110%, 111 .. 120 %, which is infeasible). I would like to give the algorithm the chance to recognize "less is better" (or more is better), but avoid 110 % and 120%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did it, was that I included a conditional statement that set the fitness of all solutions that are out of bounds to 0, making then "unselectable" for next generations.

For instance (in matlab):

```
    for i=1:population_size
        if bin2dec(population(i))>6
            population_fitness(i)=0
        end
        population_fitness(i)=bin2dec(population(i)/6
    end
```

This way the solutions that are out of your boundaries will be considered infeasible, and have 0 probability of being chosen for the next generation.